# create bean of processor(spring batch) and inject its dependency

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-batch

I need to create bean batch-processor for testing(in the controller). This processor have property @Value and I can't understand how I can create this bean.

I'm trying  like:

> autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(portfolioDataCalculationProcessor);

but it doesn't work because can initialize/set @Value property.

```
public class PortfolioDataCalculationProcessor implements ItemProcessor<PortfolioCalculationData, PortfolioCalculationResultData>, StepExecutionListener {
    @Value("#{jobParameters['" + BatchUtils.KEY_UUID + "']}")
    private String jobProcessingId;
....
```

any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replaced annotation in the processor to this, because this field(jobProcessingId) is not necessary for testing:

```
@Value("#{getObject('jobParameters') != null ? jobParameters['" + BatchUtils.KEY_UUID + "']: '0'}")
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to access jobparameters the bean should be defined in "step" scope.